# RDBMS: Is there a performance hit for co-locating columns that are not usually queried together?

Tags: postgresql

Example: We have columns `id`, `A1`, `A2`, `A3`, `B1`, `B2`, `B3`. The `A` columns are usually queried together, as are the `B` columns, but `A` are not usually queried at the same time as `B`.

Is there a performance hit for (1) storing all columns in one table, vs. (2) splitting one table for `A` columns and one table for `B` columns (which requires duplicating the `id` column)?

I am using Postgres.

Comment: Probably depends on the volume. But unless you have a godzillion rows, I doubt it would be worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes: All columns in one table makes reading each row more expensive because there are fewer rows per page, therefore more pages need to be read - more I/O.

2) Yes: Two separate tables is slower when you do need both As and Bs as you would need to join them together.  This typically has more I/O.

Generally you're going to be trading off one for another.  If you're always going to be consuming or using a small, well-indexed set, it probably won't matter.  If you're going to trawl through a large number of rows, either because of no useful indexing or a large output, then you'd be better of measuring it with your specific scenarios than guessing or even applying rules of thumb.